# Substrings search (Aho-Corasick algorithm)

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, complexity

I have a code where the goal is to give score to strings based on how much score certain substrings are worth (including repeating substrings).

The way my code (which is based on the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)) works is:

1. Creating a tree-like data structure where each node represents one prefix of a string (or the full string, along with the data needed to calculate score for this match) from the set of substrings being searched for, with some extra links pointing from some of the nodes `a` to a node that represents the largest suffix of the string that `a` represents, to avoid backtracking.
2. The search function uses this structure to find all the substrings (not remembering the matched results, only adding score if a match is found) with near O(N) complexity in most cases.

The performance bottleneck of my code is `interlink()` which creates these "extra links" in the tree, everything else works reasonably fast, any suggestions for how to improve this function's time complexity or merge it with the tree creation process (while reducing time complexity) are greatly appreciated.

The input strings for `createTree()` and `scan()` are expected to contain only lowercase a-z characters, and they can get as long as millions of chars.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tree{
    private int[] scores;
    private int[] scoreIndexes;
    private Tree[] branches = new Tree[26];
    private Tree link;

    private Tree(){}
    /**
     * @param strs - The substrings this tree will search for.
     * @param scores - An array of equal length to <b>strs</b> where each <i>scores[i]</i> represents how much score <i>strs[i]</i> is worth.
     */
    public Tree(String[] strs, int[] scores){
        this.scores = scores;
        Tree currentNode;
        String str;
        int strLength;

        for(int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++){
            currentNode = this;
            str = strs[i];
            strLength = str.length();

            for(int c = 0; c < strLength; c++){
                int idx = str.charAt(c) - 'a';
                if(currentNode.branches[idx] == null)
                    currentNode.branches[idx] = new Tree();
                currentNode = currentNode.branches[idx];
                if(strLength == c + 1)
                    currentNode.addScoreIndex(i);
            }
        }
        interlink();
    }

    /**
     * @param str - The string to be scanned.
     * @param minIdx - The first index from which scores from the tree's <b>scores</b> array are counted towards the total value of <b>str</b>.
     * @param maxIdx - The last index from which scores from the tree's <b>scores</b> array are counted towards the total value of <b>str</b>.
     * @return - The score <b>str</b> is worth.
     */
    public long scan(String str, int minIdx, int maxIdx){
        long score = 0L;
        ArrayList<Tree> nodes = new ArrayList<Tree>();
        int branchIndex;
        Tree node;
        for(int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++){
            branchIndex = str.charAt(index) - 'a';

            for(int e = 0; e < nodes.size(); e++) // advance nodes to next char
                nodes.set(e, nodes.get(e).branches[branchIndex]);

            while(nodes.remove(null));
            if(nodes.isEmpty()){ // if no nodes left, continue the search from first node
                nodes.add(this.branches[branchIndex]);
                nodes.remove(null);
            }
            for(int e = 0; e < nodes.size(); e++){
                node = nodes.get(e);
                if(node.link != null)
                    if(!nodes.contains(node.link))
                        nodes.add(node.link);

                if(node.scoreIndexes != null)
                    for(int x = 0; x < node.scoreIndexes.length; x++)
                        if(node.scoreIndexes[x] >= minIdx && node.scoreIndexes[x] <= maxIdx)
                            score += scores[node.scoreIndexes[x]];
            }
        }
        return score;
    }

    /** Creates links in the tree, which are used to avoid backtracking in <b>scan(...)</b>. */
    private void interlink(){
        int[] path = new int[1];
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            if(branches[i] != null){
                path[0] = i;
                branches[i].interlinkRecursive(this, path);
            }
    }
    private void interlinkRecursive(Tree mainTree, int[] path){
        int pathLength = path.length;
        int[] newPath = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            if(branches[i] != null){
                if(newPath == null)
                    newPath = Arrays.copyOf(path, pathLength + 1);
                newPath[pathLength] = i;
                branches[i].interlinkRecursive(mainTree, newPath);
            }
        if(pathLength < 2) return;
        Tree node;
        for(int k = 1; k < pathLength; k++){
            node = mainTree;
            for(int c = k; c < pathLength; c++){
                node = node.branches[path[c]];
                if(node == null) break;
            }
            if(node != null){
                link = node;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addScoreIndex(int index){
        if(scoreIndexes == null) scoreIndexes = new int[1];
        else scoreIndexes = Arrays.copyOf(scoreIndexes, scoreIndexes.length + 1);
        scoreIndexes[scoreIndexes.length - 1] = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to work. I always get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I try to run it. It would also be good to know how the class should be used.

Comment: `createTree()`'s first input is the substrings to be found, and the second input must be of equal length - representing the score each substring is worth. `scan()`'s inputs are: `str` is the string to search substrings in. the other two are the min and max index to count score for in the substrings array, you can just use `minIdx = 0; maxIdx = strs.length;` for testing. @aventurin

Comment: If the `path` parameter of `interlink` can become long then the nested for-loop's O(n^2) time complexity might be the cause of the performance degradation.

Comment: @aventurin This is indeed the cause of the performance degradation, my question is how to improve this time complexity

Comment: I don't understand why you have the outer loop. Sure you need it?

Comment: @aventurin I need it because I'm creating links to **suffixes** and not **prefixes**, this means I need to go through different nodes in the tree if the first (longest) suffix isn't found.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I did not incorporate answers, only other changes I made since posting the code (which are not directly related to my question), as well as adding documentation so people know how to test it.

Comment: @potato Okay, I just acted automatically as it contained several changes. I rolledback my rollback now. Keep on coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, the trick was to create the links row by row in the tree so I can use the links in the higher rows to find the largest suffix faster. Now it's complexity is O(N). Here is the final code: (also includes some other changes I made like adding support for bigger numbers)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Tree{
    private int[] scores;
    private int[] scoreIndexes;
    private Tree[] branches = new Tree[26];
    private Tree link, parent, shortcut;

    private Tree(){}
    /**
     * @param strs - The substrings this tree will search for.
     * @param scores - An array of equal length to <b>strs</b> where each <i>scores[i]</i> represents how much score <i>strs[i]</i> is worth.
     */
    public Tree(String[] strs, int[] scores){
        this.scores = scores;
        Tree currentNode;
        String str;
        int strLength;

        for(int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++){
            currentNode = this;
            str = strs[i];
            strLength = str.length();

            for(int c = 0; c < strLength; c++){
                int idx = str.charAt(c) - 'a';
                if(currentNode.branches[idx] == null){
                    currentNode.branches[idx] = new Tree();
                    currentNode.branches[idx].parent = currentNode;
                }
                currentNode = currentNode.branches[idx];
                if(strLength == c + 1)
                    currentNode.addScoreIndex(i);
            }
        }
        interlink();
    }

    /**
     * @param str - The string to be scanned.
     * @param minIdx - The first index from which scores from the tree's <b>scores</b> array are counted towards the total value of <b>str</b>.
     * @param maxIdx - The last index from which scores from the tree's <b>scores</b> array are counted towards the total value of <b>str</b>.
     * @return - The score <b>str</b> is worth.
     */
    public BigInteger scan(String str, int minIdx, int maxIdx){
        BigInteger score = new BigInteger("0");
        //long score = 0;
        Tree currentNode = this;
        Tree nextNode;
        int branchIndex;
        int strLength = str.length();
        for(int c = 0; c < strLength; c++){
            branchIndex = str.charAt(c) - 'a';

            while((nextNode = currentNode.branches[branchIndex]) == null){
                if(currentNode == this){
                    if(++c == strLength) return score;
                    branchIndex = str.charAt(c) - 'a';
                }
                else currentNode = currentNode.link;
            }
            currentNode = nextNode;

            while(nextNode != null){
                score = score.add(new BigInteger(Long.toString(nextNode.getScore(scores, minIdx, maxIdx))));// += nextNode.getScore(scores, minIdx, maxIdx);
                nextNode = nextNode.shortcut;
            }
        }
        return score;
    }

    private void interlink(){

        Queue<Tree> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(this);
        Tree node;
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            node = queue.poll();
            for(int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++)
                if(node.branches[i] != null){
                    node.branches[i].setLinks(i);
                    queue.add(node.branches[i]);
                }
        }
    }
    private void setLinks(int index){
        Tree currentNode = parent;
        while(link == null){
            if(currentNode.parent == null){
                link = currentNode;
            }
            else{
                currentNode = currentNode.link;
                link = currentNode.branches[index];
            }
        }
        shortcut = link;
        while(shortcut != null){
            if(shortcut.scoreIndexes != null)
                break;
            shortcut = shortcut.link;
        }
    }

    private void addScoreIndex(int index){
        if(scoreIndexes == null) scoreIndexes = new int[1];
        else scoreIndexes = Arrays.copyOf(scoreIndexes, scoreIndexes.length + 1);
        scoreIndexes[scoreIndexes.length - 1] = index;
    }

    private long getScore(int[] scores, int minIdx, int maxIdx){
        long score = 0;
        if(scoreIndexes != null)
            for(int x = 0; x < scoreIndexes.length; x++)
                if(scoreIndexes[x] >= minIdx && scoreIndexes[x] <= maxIdx)
                    score += scores[scoreIndexes[x]];
        return score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

Note that what follows are guesses because I can't run your code, but might gives you an idea for better performance.

---

First thing in your `interlink` method you call `path.length()` a few times, the Sun implementation is **O(1)** but it still adds function calls for no good reason (unless the compiler is smart enough to change it itself). So I'd do something like that:

```
private void interlink(Tree mainTree, String path){
    int pathLength = path.length(); // compute it once here
    for(int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
        if(branches[i] != null)
            branches[i].interlink(mainTree, path + (char)(i + 'a'));
    }
    if(pathLength < 2) return;
    Tree node;
    for(int k = 1; k < pathLength; k++){

        node = mainTree;
        for(int c = k; c < pathLength; c++){
            node = node.branches[path.charAt(c) - 'a'];
            if(node == null)
                break;
        }
        if(node != null){
            link = node;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it also is a good things to keep in mind in general as function calls are sometimes expensives.

Another thing is you could use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to do the String concatenation.

```
for(int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
    if(branches[i] != null)
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(path);
        builder.append((char)(i + 'a'));
        branches[i].interlink(mainTree, builder.toString());
}
```

But the overhead of creating a new `StringBuilder` inside the loop might kill the performance even more.

Last thing I see is `(char)(i + 'a')`. Instead of casting the char, if you had an array of char like:

```
char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c' ....};
```

You could use it like

```
for(int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
    if(branches[i] != null)
        branches[i].interlink(mainTree, path + alphabet[i]);
}
```

(or with the `StringBuilder` version)

And maybe make it a `static` member of your class `Tree` to not have a separate copy of it on all instance of your `Tree`.

---

All of those above are cheap tricks that probably won't make your program run ten times as fast, the biggest gain would be to call `interlink` less but I cannot see how to do that right now. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, making a static list of chars and storing the value of `path.length()` made a little difference, but overall the performance is still about the same. My problem is in the algorithm design, need to find a better way to create these links with less time complexity, maybe somehow incorporate it into the process of constructing the tree in `createTree()`, improving time complexity is the only thing that can make a big difference in performance here.

Comment: Creation of a local StringBuilder is exactly what happens under the hood when you perform string catenation with "+". Thus the code you write in the StringBuilder paragraph is equivalent to the original `path + (char)(i + 'a')`. You might however get rid of the repeated object instantiation by creating a StringBuilder once and reusing it (setLength(0)). (Though I doubt that this has any serious effect, as object creation is really cheap nowadays.)

Comment: Thanks @mtj I totally overlooked `setLength(0)` to reset the StringBuilder. And good to know that string concatenation is done automatically

Comment: I replaced the `path` string with an int array, using it in such a way that I only need to copy it once in each node instead of once for every branch of that node, and it doesn't require subtracting `'a'` from the chars to get the index.